# intercambiar de posición un dato mayor por uno menor

Tags: python

Quiero cambiar de posición los números mayor por menor, independientemente de donde estén dentro de una lista en Python

```
Lista = [1,2,3,7,8,9,4,5,6]    

def bubbleSort(array):
    n = len(Lista)
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(0, n-1):
            if Lista[j] > Lista[j+1]:

bubbleSort(Lista)

print(Lista)
```

```
Lista = [9,2,3,7,8,1,4,5,6]
```

Comment: no entiendo para que ordenar la lista si solo intercambias 2 elementos en este caso

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Intercambiar el valor de `Lista[j]` con el de `Lista[j+1]`**

Se utiliza una variable "temporal". Esta es una solución clásica que aplica a cualquier lenguaje.

```
temp = Lista[j]
Lista[j] = Lista[j+1]
Lista[j+1] = temp
```

Aunque Python no deja de ser algo hermoso al momento de escribir código y casi que se escucha música angelical cuando uno ve que se puede asignar una tupla intercambiando el orden.

```
Lista[j], Lista[j+1] = Lista[j+1], Lista[j]
```

Comment: Es sólo parte de la solución; no la solución completa.

Comment: @CandidMoe creo que tenés razón, que interpreté mal la pregunta (fijate que era la línea que le faltaba al código para ordenar -y no presté atención al ejemplo... el título es muy malo jaja)

Answer (score 3):

òtra forma, sin necesidad de ordenar la lista.

```
Lista = [1,2,3,7,8,9,4,5,6]

def cambia(lista):
    #realizo una copia de la lista como un objeto nuevo
    copia_Lista=list(lista)
    
    #la función index obtiene la posición de un elemento en la lista
    #la función min el elemento mínimo de la lista
    #la función max el elemento máximo de la lista
    #busco el mínimo y máximo en la copia y los asigno a la lista original 
    lista[copia_Lista.index(min(copia_Lista))] = copia_Lista[copia_Lista.index(max(copia_Lista))]
    lista[copia_Lista.index(max(copia_Lista))] = copia_Lista[copia_Lista.index(min(copia_Lista))]
    
    #prefiero hacerlo en una única línea pero por una custión de legibilidad lo hago en dos ahora
    return lista

print(cambia(Lista))
```

Answer (score 2):

Intercambiar menor y mayor de una lista sin importar donde se encuentren.

Usemos esta lista como ejemplo:

```
lista = [10,2,36,7,81,9,46,57,6]
```

El elemento menor es lista[1], el mayor es lista[4].

Solución:

```
def intercambia(lista):
    if len(lista):
        x = sorted(enumerate(lista), key=lambda y: y[1])
        menor = x[0][0]
        mayor = x[-1][0]
        lista[menor],lista[mayor] = lista[mayor],lista[menor]
    return lista
```

**Análisis**

La función `enumerate` crea una lista de tuplas donde el primer elemento es el índice y el segundo el valor de la lista en esa posición. Por tanto, `enumerate(lista)` produce:

```
(0, 10) (1, 2) (2, 36) (3, 7) (4, 81) (5, 9) (6, 46) (7, 57) (8, 6)
```

Ahora ordenamos ese resultado usando `sorted` sobre el segundo item de cada tupla `sorted(enumerate(lista), key=lambda y: y[1])`. Produce:

```
[(1, 2), (8, 6), (3, 7), (5, 9), (0, 10), (2, 36), (6, 46), (7, 57), (4, 81)]
```

Ahora sólo queda extraer los indices del primer y último elemento, que corresponden al menor y mayor valor respectivamente. El primer elemento es `x[0]`, el último es `x[-1]`. Ambos son tuplas; sólo me interesa el índice, que está en la primera posición:

```
menor = x[0][0]
mayor = x[-1][0]
```

y luego intercambio ambos sin tocar el resto de la lista:

```
lista[menor],lista[mayor] = lista[mayor],lista[menor]
```

produce:

```
[10, 81, 36, 7, 2, 9, 46, 57, 6]
```

**Demo**

```
tests = [[],
         [1],
         [1,2],
         [2,1],
         [1,2,3,4,5],
         [5,4,3,2,1],
         [10, 2, 1, 0],
         [10, 2, 36, 7, 81, 9, 46, 57, 6],
         [5, -1, 6, 8, 10, 4]]

for test in tests:
    print(f"original: {test}")
    print(f"nuevo   : {intercambia(test)}")
    print()
```

Ojo: hay que imprimir `test` antes de llamar a `intercambiar`. Si se imprimen ambos en el mismo `print`, saldrá el valor actual en ambos casos.

Resultado

```
original: []
nuevo   : []

original: [1]
nuevo   : [1]

original: [1, 2]
nuevo   : [2, 1]

original: [2, 1]
nuevo   : [1, 2]

original: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
nuevo   : [5, 2, 3, 4, 1]

original: [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
nuevo   : [1, 4, 3, 2, 5]

original: [2, 10, 2, 0, 1]
nuevo   : [2, 0, 2, 10, 1]

original: [10, 2, 36, 7, 81, 9, 46, 57, 6]
nuevo   : [10, 81, 36, 7, 2, 9, 46, 57, 6]

original: [5, -1, 6, 8, 10, 4]
nuevo   : [5, 10, 6, 8, -1, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer uso del método reverse de la siguiente manera:

`Lista.reverse()`

`Print(Lista)`

Comment: `reverse` da vuelta toda la lista. El OP pregunta cómo intercambiar sólo el mayor con el menor.

Comment: No está bien redactada la pregunta.